# How can I automatically implement FromIterator?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have written a trait that specifies some methods similar to those of [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```
pub trait Buffer {
    type Item;
    fn with_capacity(c: usize) -> Self;
    fn push(&mut self, item: Self::Item);
}
```

I would like to implement [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) for all types that implement `Buffer`, as follows:

```
impl<T> iter::FromIterator<T::Item> for T
    where T: Buffer
{
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator<Item = T>
    {
        let mut iter = iter.into_iter();
        let (lower, _) = iter.size_hint();
        let ans = Self::with_capacity(lower);
        while let Some(x) = iter.next() {
            ans.push(x);
        }
        ans
    }
}
```

The compiler won't let me:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter
for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`); only traits defined in the
current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

I think I understand the error message; it is preventing me from writing code that is incompatible with possible future changes to the standard library.

The only way around this error appears to be to implement `FromIterator` separately for every type for which I implement `Buffer`. This will involve copying out exactly the same code many times. Is there a a way to share the same implementation between all `Buffer` types?

Comment: *with possible future changes to the standard library* — not just the standard library, but any library that your code may link (or be linked to) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement a trait from another crate for an arbitrary type, only for a type from your crate. However, you can move the implementation to a function and reduce amount of duplicated code:

```
fn buffer_from_iter<I, B>(iter: I) -> B
    where I: IntoIterator<Item = B::Item>, 
          B: Buffer
{
    let mut iter = iter.into_iter();
    let (lower, _) = iter.size_hint();
    let mut ans = B::with_capacity(lower);
    while let Some(x) = iter.next() {
        ans.push(x);
    }
    ans
}

struct S1;
impl Buffer for S1 {
    type Item = i32;
    fn with_capacity(c: usize) -> Self { unimplemented!() }
    fn push(&mut self, item: Self::Item) { unimplemented!() }
}

impl std::iter::FromIterator<<S1 as Buffer>::Item> for S1 {
    fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> Self
        where I: IntoIterator<Item = <S1 as Buffer>::Item>
    {
        buffer_from_iter(iter)
    }
}
```

This implementation of `FromIterator` can be wrapped into a macro to further reduce code duplication.

Comment: Better still, your `buffer_from_iter` can be `Buffer::from_iter`, so as to remove a type variable and lots of "as Buffer" clauses. I worked this much out by myself. :-( The idea of using a macro is good; I wouldn't mind writing "buffer_from_iter!(MyType)" occasionally. I will accept an answer that shows how to do that.

Comment: How about this? (Learning as I go along!)
https://gist.github.com/apt1002/1b5139f0e0d4e700b5732e0ae44fe3fb